# How to Save Data from Input Type Text Without Submit Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I have a new website. In this website, the user enters values in the Name & Email in text fields and then the user clicks an anchor to get a unique link.

Now the thing is, I want to save data from input type `text` (Name & Email). I know how to do it if there is a submit button, but how can I save data without a submit button?

I want to save data in a database via PHP.

Comment: show what have you tried?

Comment: Can you show your attempt(s) please? Also if you don't want a submit button, how do you plan to detect the client has finished inputting data into the Name & Email fields?

Comment: you got to have an event that will fire so you can save your data.. if you dont want a button then you can have keyup on input but that is just to difficult since you have multiple input... but i think having a button is the best option

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to submit your form without using a submit button.
Use the code written below and modify it accordingly:

```
<form name="myform">
     <input type="text" />
     <button class="buttonFinish"></button>
 </form>

 <script type="javascipt">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buttonFinish').click(function(){
            $('.myform').submit();
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: It works!!! I think this is one of the ways where you can submit without using submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Made an AJAX call on key enter by checking  if(keycode == '13')
and call your server side method by validating it.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment as this doesn't really offer any solution/answer, this is more of a Suggestion with no example/source code.